# Is it possible to send arguments to Nightwatch from the command line?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, soapui, nightwatch.js

I have a jenkins job that makes an XML request and returns an answer. From this answer I have a string I need on nightwatch to start the tests.

Does anyone know how I can send this string to nightwatch? Maybe via a command line argument? But how to read it next?

Comment: What does this have to do with the tool [tag:soapui]?

Comment: Hey @anubis, any updates on this? Want me to suggest something else, or did you manage to make it work with the classic environment variables? [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) is another thing you can try, but you have to setup additional logic to support it.

Comment: Hey @iamdanchiv, I have at the end do that with file. Soapui write the result to a file and then in javascript side I read the file to find the value. Maybe not the best solution but I does the job.

Comment: @anubis, glad you made it work, even though that sounds a bit painful. You should always avoid getting values from file, as those are also technically static, hardcoded values. Any change in content & you have to go and update the file data.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using a NodeJS-based framework, why not make use of a [process.env](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) variable?

Suppose you need to tell your script what environment you want to run your checks agains. Let's call our system variable `ENV`. Your command will become:

`ENV=prod nightwatch nightwatch.conf.js --yourOtherSwitches`

In your page-objects/feature-files, you call the variable using `process.env.ENV`.